# Base_url() not working on codeigniter

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter bootstrap stylesheet link URL can't work properly.
Controller code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $data['title'] = "Login Home";
        $this->load->view('home',$data);
    }
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="well">
                <h3>welcome</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS link code

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url("register/application/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: set bootstrap-3.3.6 in your root directory under register folder

Comment: how to set the root directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in config.php set this line

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/register/';
```

root directory set this way

```
application
system    
bootstrap-3.3.6
```

Answer (score 3):

> **Place assets out side of application**. Reason the .htaccess in application folder blocks it.

```
application
assets
assets > bootstrap > css > bootstrap.css
assets > bootstrap > js > bootstrap.js
system
index.php
```

First I would suggest

config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

then

config/config.php Set your base url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectnmame/';
```

Answer (score 0):

ensure that you are using .htaccess file in your codeigniter application.create one folder assets.place your css file in assets folder.after that link that file like  this,

in application folder config file paste this,

```
$root = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);;

$config['base_url'] = $root;







<link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/register/application/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

if you are not using htaccess file,

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url("index.php/assets/register/application/bootstrap-3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

try this....